# TYPO3 v6.1 TemplaVoila - add userFunc to specific template part

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.1.x

how can I replace programmatically via TypoScript the content of {content_left} in a single page via USER_INT with individual PHP content.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header span-28">
    <f:format.raw>{header}</f:format.raw> 
  </div>
    <img class="logo" src="../fileadmin/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <a href="./"><img class="headerimg" src="../fileadmin/header_img.png" alt="headerimg"></a>
  <div class="menu span-28">
    <f:format.raw>{main_menu}</f:format.raw>
  </div>
  <div class="service span-28">
    <f:format.raw>{service_menu}</f:format.raw>
  </div>
  <div class="content span-6 append-1">
    <f:format.raw>{content_left}</f:format.raw>
  </div>
  <div class="content span-22 last">
    <f:format.raw>{content_right}</f:format.raw>
  </div>
  <div class="footer span-28 last">
    <f:format.raw>{footer}</f:format.raw>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current TypoScript does look like this:

```
# 
temp.info = USER_INT
temp.info {
  userFunc = user_various->listContentRecordsOnPage
  reverseOrder = 1
  debugOutput = 1
}
page.content_left < temp.info
```

But it does not work. :( No replacement is done.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers
kk3003

---

gsnerf is absolutety right, it's a FLUIDTEMPLATE element.
Unfortunately this TYPOSCRIPT set to the single page where it should appear does not work, any ideas please?

```
# Include the PHP file with custom code
includeLibs.user_various = fileadmin/php/example_listRecords.php

# 
temp.info = USER_INT
temp.info {
  userFunc = user_various->listContentRecordsOnPage
}

page = PAGE
page {
   typeNum = 0

   metaCharset = utf-8

   includeCSS{
    file10  = fileadmin/css/blueprint/screen.css
    file20  = fileadmin/css/blueprint/print.css
    file20.media = print

    file100 = fileadmin/css/main.css
    file300 = fileadmin/css/service.css
    file400 = fileadmin/css/mainMenu.css
    file500 = fileadmin/css/sliding-box.css
    file600 = fileadmin/css/gridelements.css
   }

   includeJS {
        file10 = fileadmin/js/accordion.js
   }
}

[browser = msie]
page.includeCSS.file30 = fileadmin/css/blueprint/ie.css
page.includeCSS.file30.media = screen
[global]

page.meta {
  MSSmartTagsPreventParsing = true
  imagetoolbar  = false
}

# https_enforcer
page.5 < plugin.tx_httpsenforcer_pi1

# Create a Fluid Template
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  # Set the Template Pathes
  file = fileadmin/templates/html/template.html
  partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/html/partials/
  layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/html/layouts/
  variables {
    header < lib.header
    content_left < lib.contentLeft
    content_right < temp.info
    main_menu < lib.mainMenu
    service_menu < lib.serviceMenu
    footer < lib.footer
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this is supposed to have to do with templavoila? This seems more like fluid to me. If that is the case you have to replace your

```
page.content_left < temp.info
```

with the following:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    [...]

    variables.content_left < temp.info
}
```

Assuming you already have a FLUIDTEMPLATE definition you only need to copy the variables line into that one.

Comment: Hi gsnerf, thanks for your answer. Please see my update above. thx!

Comment: Ok, got it. I need to include that stuff in an own subtemplate of the page. ;) I just added it as TS to the page. Thx.